# Can't retrieve DB info

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I need help figuring out why the following DB Query is not working. I know the DB connection is good. I also know the `$referralname = $_SESSION['user_name'];` is correctly rendering. It has to be something with my code.

I am getting the following errors. Maybe this will help to figure this out.

```
[12-Jun-2013 21:13:54 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /x/x/public_html/americansolar/partner/classes/Referral.php on line 89
[12-Jun-2013 21:13:54 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /x/x/public_html/americansolar/partner/classes/Referral.php on line 90
```

P.S. I am not sure if the while statement is necessary or not since it will always only return one result???

**My Code:**

```
// creating a database connection
$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

// if no connection errors (= working database connection)
if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {


      $referralname = $_SESSION['user_name'];


      // get the referrer's id
      $query_get_referral_id = $this->db_connection->query("SELECT * From users WHERE user_name = '".$referralname."';");
      $result = MYSQL_QUERY($query_get_referral_id);
      $numberOfRows = MYSQL_NUM_ROWS($result);
      $i = 0;
        while ($i<$numberOfRows)
        {
                  $thisId = MYSQL_RESULT($result,$i,"user_id");

                  $i++;
            }
}
```

**My Solution:**

```
$query_get_referral_id = $this->db_connection->query("SELECT * From users WHERE user_name = '".$referralname."';");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_get_referral_id))
  {
      $thisId = $row['user_id'];
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre mixing [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)... they are two completely different and incompatible interfaces. Secondly, your `$query_get_referral_id` is not an id value... it is a [`mysqli_result` object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). You need to then extract the value from that object.

And lastly... DONT use [mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)... stick with [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

---

Also you should use a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for this:

```
$stmt = $this->db_connection->query("SELECT user_id From users WHERE user_name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $referralname);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->num_rows) {
   
   $stmt->bind_result($userId);

   while($stmt->fetch()) {
        // do something with $userId...
        // each iteration of this loop is a 
        // row of the result set, it will automatically
        // load the value of the user_id into $userId
   }
}
```

Comment: Ahh that explains a lot :) So what do I need to change this too in order to keep the mysqli_result format?  `$result = MYSQL_QUERY($query_get_referral_id);`

Comment: Thanks prod! Can you explain further on how to put the user_id row into a variable inside the  while loop? Also, is there no need to loop this with a variable `$i++`? Sorry, just used to the old ways of doing it :)

Comment: Also I am getting this error with the code like it is.. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` Thanks!

Comment: I found another way of doing it :) I added to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I donot think you should query like

```
$query_get_referral_id = $this->db_connection->query("SELECT * From users WHERE user_name = '".$referralname."';");
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($query_get_referral_id);
```

Well, you should go

```
$result = $this->db_connection->query("SELECT * From users WHERE user_name = '".$referralname."';");
```